# How to set background image on xamarin forms master detail page and android

Tags: xamarin, navigation, master-detail, renderer

I want to set a navigation bar background image, but so far, no methods worked.
I don't know if I have to override the navigation-page renderer or if I have to change the "styles.xml", or if I have to override the Android "Toolbar", I have tried everything and I can't seem to find the solution.
I am using Xamarin Forms and Master Detail Page navigation.

I already tried changing styles.xml, making a custom toolbar layout, but doesn't mean I have done it right.

```xml
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```